# Why cant I print out my array of objects in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, array

I am trying to prepare a list of objects that I am pushing to another service, I have generated a list of objects that need to be sent. For some reason I cannot stringify the array.

This is my code:

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    Write("generating person " + i + "<br>");
    var person = {};
    person.name = "Jane " + i;
    array[i] = person;
}
Write("length:" + array.length)
Write("<br><br>==========<br>")
Write(Stringify(array[1]));
Write("<br>")
Write(Stringify(array));
Write("<br><br>==========<br>")
```

But this is what is returned:

```
generating person 1
generating person 2
generating person 3
generating person 4
length:4

==========
{"name":"Jane 1"}
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why, but it seems `Stringify()` can't handle something you completely omit: `array[0]` - it never has a value assigned.

Start you for loop from `i = 0` and it works.

Comment: you're right, this is interesting then... does this mean we cannot associate a key to the element in the array? I have strings that I wanted to use, but if I have to use an integer and start from 0 it means that wont work.

Comment: Arrays will always start from 0. Why are you saying that starting from 0 is a problem? i = 0 can be be used to generate 'Jane 1' easily. The other service won't care about indexing in this array